# Ansible-galaxy pre_tasks do not seem to execute before the roles

Tags: ansible

Here is my `playbook.yaml`

```
  pre_tasks:

    - name: Install required ansible-galaxy roles
      local_action: shell ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml

  roles:
    - role: gantsign.golang
      vars:
        golang_version: "1.16.3"
        golang_install_dir: "/opt/go/{{ golang_version }}"
```

And my `requirements.yaml`

```
---
- src: gantsign.golang
```

However the `pre_task` never seems to be executed, so the role is not found and provisioning fails.

Any idea why?

```
ERROR! the role 'gantsign.golang' was not found in /home/pkaramol/ansible

The error appears to be in '/home/pkaramol/ansible/airflow-playbook.yaml': line 33, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - role: gantsign.golang
      ^ here
```

It looks as if `ansible` is trying to find the roles before starting the playbook. For some reason I am pretty sure I had done this process before (i.e. having a `pre_task` with `local_action` taking over role installation but I cannot seem to get it working now...)

**edit**: I have confirmed that this is the case, because when leaving only the `pre_task` with the local role installation it actually runs

Comment: Hello, have you try to run the single shell command out of the play ?

Comment: yes it works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in that documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level

> When you use the roles option at the play level, Ansible treats the roles as static imports and processes them during playbook parsing. Ansible executes your playbook in this order ...

So The role itself need to be found and load before the playbook start running.

So if you want to use galaxy on pre_tasks, try to dynamically include your role on tasks section of your play: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#include-role-module

```html
pre_tasks:

  - name: Install required ansible-galaxy roles
    local_action: shell ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml

tasks:
  - name: include my roles
    include_role:
      name: gantsign.golang
```